# Is crisp pixel scaling in Motion possible? (instead of anti-aliasing)

Tags: motion

Is it possible to export sharp pixels (similar to nearest neighbour interpolation in Photoshop, or image-rendering: pixelated in CSS) from within Motion?

I would like to work with small 1:1 pixel objects and scale them — but I don't want them antialiased.

In Premiere you get this rendering setting with Draft mode. Unfortunately Motion's Draft mode doesn't seem to use nearest-neighbour interpolation.